# Is it better to use pointers to objects in an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm dabbling around with C++ and trying to wrap my head around the pointer thing. When creating an array of objects, is it better to create the array of the object type or of pointers?

For instance:

`Block grid[size];` or `Block* grid[size];`

From what I've been reading I was under the impression that when using objects it's almost always better to use pointers to save memory? Eventually I'm going to create a dynamically allocated 2D array of these objects, and I'm wondering if it's worth hassling to try and store them as pointers in the multidimensional array.

NOTE: I have been told to look into 2D vectors, when it comes to dynamically creating them and allocating them I'm struggling just as much as with these arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not using standard containers like `std::vector<Block> grid(size);`?

Comment: Like I said in the NOTE, I'm struggling just as much with creating 2D standard vectors. And then the same question still applies, do I make the vectors of type Block or Block*?

Comment: Using pointers only saves memory when you re-use the same object. For example, if the same Block appears multiple times in your array, otherwise it uses up an extra `sizeof(Block*)*size` bytes.

Comment: @Matt, thanks! Is using std::vector<std::Vector<Block>> preferable to my approach?

Comment: @nickcorin well that completely depends on what you are using it for. Does it need to be resizeable (you say "dynamically allocated", not necessarily the same thing)?

Comment: No, the array will be the state representation of a grid based game. The reason for the dynamic allocation is that the size of the grid is not known until run time.

Comment: @nickcorin So you don't need to use vector then as it's just created once.

Comment: Objects clean themselves up when they go out of scope, unless you created them using `new` and attached them to a *pointer*. So using objects directly is *faster*, *easier* and *safer*. You should only use *pointers* when its needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing something. A classic C-array *is* a pointer pointing to the first element. What you think of are classes which are expensive when they get (deep-)copied while calling a function or similar. These expensive function arguments (strings, vectors, and similar) are better be passed as references (or pointers).

'Modern C++' provides you with enough utility that you shouldnt use any allocation on your own, if you are not writing your own containers. You usually use pointers to point to things, that you do not own in a context. I also recommend to not use classic C-arrays anymore. Use

```
array<Block, size> grid; // compile-time constant size
```

instead of

```
Block grid[size]; // compile-time constant size
```

`array<>` will try to be on the stack. If `size` is not known to compile time, you have to allocate the memory on the heap. The STL calls these heap-arrays `vector` instead

```
vector<Block> grid(size); // runtime variable size
if (grid.size() > 0) 
   cout << grid[0]; // use grid like an array
```

The old C-style way for heap arrays was to allocate memory manually and free it after you do not need it anymore. This is very error-prone and should be avoided unless you know what you do.

As mentioned the difference to plain old arrays (which are pointers) is when calling a function. Before you had to pass a pointer and potentially the size of the array

```
void fancy_old_function(Block* grid, size_t size) // BAD practise
{
    // do things
}

// ...
{
    Block grid[size];
    fancy_old_function(grid, size); // error prone
    ...
    // maybe alot later
    fancy_old_function(grid, 13); // ohoh! 13 < size?
}
```

In C++ and with big objects you should pass these as a reference (or make it a pointer) otherwise your vector gets deep copied.

```
void fancy_new_function(vector<Block>& grid) // GOOD
{
   // do fancy stuff an potentially change grid
}
```

The drawback is now, that we have different signatures for dynamic and static arrays:

```
template <size_t N>
void fancy_new_function(array<Block, N>& grid) // GOOD
{
   // do fancy stuff an potentially change grid
}
```

A huge improvement to classic C-arrays is, that we know the size of an array implicitly at all times.

You can call your `fancy_new_function` like this:

```
{ 
   array<Block,size> grid1;
   fancy_new_function(grid1); // size is implicitly deduced
                              // or use grid1.size();

   vector<Block> grid2(size);
   fancy_new_function(grid2); // developer can use grid2.size()
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This really explained things really nicely. I guess I was overthinking things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Block grid[size]`, because why would you create an array of pointers (the only reason I can think of is for an array with unknown size at compile time)  In terms of memory, the pointers are a bit more expensive, because their address and their content is stored (on the stack and on the heap respectively). And you can't forget to deallocate them when you are done with them, otherwise you will get a memory leak.

---

The better alternative would be `std::array<Block, size> grid`, or even `std::vector<Block> grid`.

`std::vector` is like an `std::array`, but its dynamic, without a fixed size (so you can change it a runtime, for example).

Comment: I'm not sure why I didn't add it into the question, but the reason for the dynamic allocation is that I will not know the size at compile time. The array is an attribute in a class that will be created at run time.

Comment: @nickcorin Ok, so you can use `std::vector`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is in a function, it doesn't 'save' memory.
One implementation uses more stack memory.
The other uses less stack memory, but uses more heap.

This entirely uses the stack:

```
Block grid[size];
```

This uses the stack to store your pointers to objects.
The memory used to store the objects is the heap:

```
Block* grid[size];
```

However, if these are global declarations, then yes, this:

```
Block grid[size];
```

does potentially waste memory because it is allocated for the lifetime of your application, and cannot be deallocated/resized.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "better" depends upon how you would the array.

If Block is small (2-8 bytes) or you need to use every element of **grid**, you'd be better off doing

```
Block grid [size] ;
```

In almost all cases.

Suppose sizeof (Block) > 512 and you do not use all the elements of **grid** and

```
  const int size = 10 ;
```

you'd probably be better off with

```
 Block grid [size] ;
```

Would probably make the most sense. On the other hand, suppose

```
const in size = 2000000 ;
```

then

```
Block *grid [size] ;
```

makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

*Better* is rather a matter of taste :-)

An array of objects may be simpler to use for simple use cases because you create and destroy the full array at once. It look a little more C++ idiomatic.

The exception I can think would be:

- performance reasons with expensive to create objects. Here you only create an array for pointers with the maximum size and create objects when you need them
- polymorphism with derived classes. IMHO this is the best use case for using arrays of pointers. Because if you try to copy a derived object into its base class, you will get object slicing: the base class copy will loose all attributes that are only present in derived class. So in that case, you create an array to pointers to the base class (it can even be abstract) and populate it with concrete implementations. And you can manipulate any object in the array with the virtual methods from the base class.